# Multipile coloring of an UILabel with saving lineHeight

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

Hello every one i have an UILabel with lineHeight 1.2 and need it to be multicolored, but as soon as I change the color of the text, the value of the lineheight becomes default.
Here is my function:

```
func configTopLabel(label: UILabel, localString: String, color: UIColor) {

   var myString:NSString = localString
   var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()
   myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myString as String, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "GothamPro-Bold", size: 22.0)!])
   let location = localString.characters.count - 3
   myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myString as String, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "GothamPro-Bold", size: 22.0)!])
   myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: color, range: NSRange(location: location,length: 3))
   label.setLineHeight(1.2)
   label.attributedText = myMutableString
}
```

Comment: How is `setLineHeight` implemented?

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried it from storyboard ?
You can set multi coloured string from storyboard (Attributes string) and set lineHeight programatically.

Comment: Can u pls tell me how can i do it? I haven't found this in storyboard.:(

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jH10D.png)

See above attached image, you'll get idea how to make custom attributed string in storyboard.